# Flask URL not found when using blueprint

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

This is really strange but am facing this problem. Everything was working and i was almost done with the app but out of a sudden it stopped. I have isolated the code and i realized that when i register a blueprint and use it on a route, it fails to return saying no URL found. Here is the isolated code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

home = Blueprint('home', __name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='template')
app.register_blueprint(home)


@home.route('/')  #<---This one does not work
# @app.route('/') <--- This one works
def index():
    return "This is the index route."
    # return render_template('layer.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 14):

Move the `app.register_blueprint(home)` after route defined.

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

home = Blueprint('home', __name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='template')

@home.route('/')  
def index():
    return "This is the index route."

app.register_blueprint(home)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: saved the day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what if the blueprint is in another file? i have the same issue but the bps are in another file and they are not registered properly (app.url_map doesnt have them)